# Where does this C# HttpContext context in Startup.cs come from?

Tags: c#, lambda, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

So I came across this [RazorPages sample code](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/razor-pages/ui-class/samples/cli/WebApp1/Startup.cs)

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }
```

and my question is, where does *context* come from? I'm looking at

```
options => { ... }
```

as an anonymous delegate function with the part to the left of the lambda operator, options, being the parameter that gets fed into the expression block where *context* is. But context doesn't show anywhere else in Startup.cs and the compiler doesn't seem to mind when I comment out

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
```

Is .Net doing something transparently behind the scenes to provide *context* to options.CheckConsentNeeded and if I were to write that statement by hand how would I know that *context* is available and where is it coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`CheckConsentNeeded`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.cookiepolicyoptions.checkconsentneeded?view=aspnetcore-3.1) property accepts a delegate of `Func<HttpContext, bool>`.

`Func<HttpContext, bool>` in C# can represent a method which takes a parameter of `HttpContext` and returns a `bool` value.

```
bool MyFunction(HttpContext context)
{
}
```

In your case, you assigned a [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) to the property, and `context` represents the parameter of type `HttpContext`. `context` is a name, you can change it to other names, such as `ctx`, `c` etc.

You do not need to add [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) to use `context`, but if you use its type `HttpContext` in your code, you have to use `using`.

> To allow the use of types in a namespace

At runtime, when the caller of the delegate, most likely in a middleware, invokes the delegate, it will pass an instance of `HttpContext` as a parameter into the delegate assigned to `CheckConsentNeeded` property.

Comment: so the runtime is the provider of httpcontext !! from what i understood its like you tell the runtime here you go here is my function and it accepts an httpcontext and the real caller is not you, its the runtime ! something like this i guess ? and if thats correct, does that mean that you are not calling any method you are just registering your function ! and i would really want to see a simple example how i can do it also !

Comment: i think i understood it , you are calling a function just like a regular function like ```console.writeline()``` but this time the parameter is another function , just like when you call ```console.writeline()``` you are intrested in what you pass in the parameter , this time the parameter is another function and when you write functions, you dont write ``` public int func(5)``` you write ```public int func(int x)```

Answer (score 1):

`Configure` allows you to pass in a lambda to configure your options. Have a look at this contrived example to explain what is happening.

```
// we have an options class that will hold all the props to configure
// our coolie policy
public class Options
{
    public bool UseConsent { get; set; }
}

// this emulates the signature for services.Configure. It takes a lambda
// and simply executes it, enabling the caller to manage the settings
public static void Configure(Action<Options> callback)
{
    //create new options instance
    var options = new Options();
    // allow caller to access this instance and set properties
    callback(options);
    Console.WriteLine(options.UseConsent); // this will print true
}


public static void Main()
{
    Configure(options =>
    {
        options.UseConsent = true;
    });
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

As you can see, there's no magic happening anywhere, the reason why you can set options or not, is because `Configure` is overloaded, allowing you to pass in a lambda or not.